# Random count generator by probability in python

Tags: python, multithreading, random

Create a function that prints a random number between 1 and 5 to stdout (or console). 
1 - 50%
2 - 25%
3 - 15%
4 - 5%
5 - 5%

Comment: Looks like a nice little practice problem. What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think exact answers will help you, each step builds on the last. Here's a start:

```
def foo():
    choices = *[1]*10, *[2]*5, *[3]*3, *[4], *[5]
    return random.choice(choices)
```

Note the leading asterisk expands the lists so we don't have [[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],...]. It's not strictly necessary for the last two items.

Comment: We usually don't answer questions that are just a dump of homework on SO.